# SCSS sourcemaps not working with Webpack 3 + ExtractTextPlugin

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, sass, source-maps

I'm trying to enable sourcemaps for my SCSS in my app and have a really puzzling situation on my hands. Here's my config file:

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssets = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');

let config = {
 entry: './src/index.ts',
 devtool: 'eval-source-map', // for choosing a style of source map
 output: {
  filename: 'bundle.js',
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist')
 },
 devServer: {
  contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'), // A directory or URL to serve HTML content from
  historyApiFallback: true, // fallback to /index.html for SPA
  inline: true,
  open: false // open default browser on launch
 },
 module: {
  rules: [
   {
    test: /\.ts$/, // files ending with .ts
    exclude: /node_modules/, // exclude the node modules directory
    use: 'ts-loader'
   },
   {
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: {
     loader: "babel-loader",
     options: {
      presets: ["env"]
     }
    }
   },
   {
    test: /\.scss$/, // files ending with .scss
    use: ['css-hot-loader'].concat(
     ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
      fallback: 'style-loader',
      use: [
       // { loader: 'style-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } },
       { loader: 'css-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } },
       { loader: 'postcss-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } },
       { loader: 'sass-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } },
      ],
     })
    )
   },
   {
    test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/, // for other file types
    use: ['file-loader?name=[name].[ext]&outputPath=img/']
   }
  ]
 },
 resolve: {
  extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
 },
 plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
   $: 'jquery',
   jQuery: 'jquery'
  }),
  new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css') // call the ExtractTextPlugin and name our CSS file
 ]
};

module.exports = config;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
 module.exports.plugins.push(
  new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(), // call the uglify plugin
  new OptimizeCSSAssets() // call the CSS optimizer (for minification)
 );
}
```

What's really strange is that here, everything in the terminal compiles fine but when I inspect an element, there's no sourcemap:

[image]

HOWEVER, if uncomment this line in my webpack.config file:

`// { loader: 'style-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } },`

and run `npm start` again, the sourcemaps work correctly!...

[image]

...but now the terminal throws an error, which apparently is because [you aren't supposed to use style-loader inside of the ExtractTextPlugin, but rather only as a fallback.](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/503) My app still works in this case, but I don't want that error! How can I enable the SCSS sourcemaps without including style-loader in my SCSS rules?